# VBA control a drop down menu

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am trying to control a drop down list on a [website](http://www.saia.com/RequestQuote.aspx), but for some reason have been unable to interact with it. Here is the HTML section that I believe is responsible from the drop down menu:

```javascript
    <div id="content">
        <div id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="formBody">
                    <h1>Get a Quote</h1>
                    <div style="width:215px; height:35px;" class="noBottomSpacing">
                      <select id="quoteDropdown" name="position">
                            <option>Select Type of Quote</option>
                            <option value="ltl">LTL Quote</option>
                            <option value="truckload">Truckload Quote</option>
                            <option value="expedited">Expedited Quote</option>
                            <option value="Mexico">Mexico Quote</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="quoteContent">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've tried several different VBA snippets but nothing seems to work.

```
    ie.Document.getElementbyID("quoteDropdown").selectedindex = 1
    ie.Document.getElementbyID("quoteDropdown").Item(0).Value = 1
    ie.Document.getElementbyID("quoteDropdown").Value = "ltl"
```

If anyone has any guidance I would appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: you could try ie.Document.getElementbyName("position")(0).Value = "ltl"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it all figured out. Thanks Nathan_Sav for pointing me to that statement. This code was changing the index but wasn't firing the event.

```
ie.document.getElementbyID("quoteDropdown").selectedindex = 1
```

In order to fire the event I had to call the function "loadquote"

`ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "loadquote('ltl')"`

this successfully called the function "loadquote" and updated the page.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim d As MSHTML.IHTMLSelectElement

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = 1

ie.navigate "http://www.saia.com/RequestQuote.aspx"

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set d = ie.document.getElementById("quoteDropdown")

'     Then use d.selectedindex or d.item(1).text d.value etc.
```

Looking at the web page source, is handled from the click event on each of the inner items, so you'll need to get those, and then fire the click event

From page  " $('#quoteDropdown').val('ltl').trigger('click').selectric('refresh');
                                loadquote('ltl');"